# Synchronous less compiling in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, less, browserify

I'm trying to write a transform script for Browserify that allows me to `require()` .less files. The transformation will compile them to CSS and then wrap that minified CSS in a little Javascript function that appends the CSS to the page.

My trouble is that the [main LESS module](https://github.com/less/less.js) is asynchronous, which doesn't appear to work alongside a transformation script:

**lessify/index.js** (Modeled directly from [node-underscorify](https://github.com/maxparm/node-underscorify/blob/master/index.js))

```
var less = require('less');
var cleanCSS = require('clean-css');
var through = require('through');

module.exports = function(file) {
    if (!/\.css|\.less/.test(file)) {
        return through();
    }
    var buffer = "";

    return through(function(chunk) {
        return buffer += chunk.toString();
    }, function() {
        compiled = buffer;
        if (/\.less/.test(file)) {
            compiled = less.render(compiled, function(e, r) { return r; });
        }
        // rv comments
        compiled = compiled.replace(/\/\*.*?\*\//g, "");

        // minify. TO DO: Get less.js to do this for us
        var compiled = cleanCSS.process(buffer);

        compiled = "(function($) { $('head').append('<style type=\"text/css\">" + compiled.replace(/'/g, "\\'") + "</style>');}(window.jQuery));";
        this.queue(compiled);
        return this.queue(null);
    });
};
```

This works just fine for .css file, but breaks on .less files since `compiled` is undefined.

There are several [completed](https://github.com/less/less.js/pull/1499) [pull requests](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1498) in the less.js source related to this, but none seem to work for me.

I'm not terribly familiar with the `through` library, so perhaps its behavior can easily be adjusted to asynchronous functions? I realize it makes sense for `less.render()` to be async by default to handle `@import`, and don't mind forgoing imports in order to be able to directly `require()` LESS on my pages.

Answer (score 1):

This actually works if slightly modified. I was being stupid above with running `cleanCSS` on `buffer`, not `compiled`

```
var less = require('less');
var cleanCSS = require('clean-css');
var through = require('through');

var parser = new(less.Parser)({
    processImports: false
});

module.exports = function(file) {
    if (!/\.css|\.less/.test(file)) {
        return through();
    }
    var buffer = "";

    return through(function(chunk) {
        return buffer += chunk.toString();
    }, function() {
        var compiled;
        // CSS is LESS so no need to check extension
        parser.parse(buffer, function(e, r) { 
            compiled = r.toCSS();
        });

        // rv comments
        compiled = compiled.replace(/\/\*.*?\*\//g, "");

        var compiled = cleanCSS.process(compiled);

        compiled = "(function($) { $('head').append('<style type=\"text/css\">" + compiled.replace(/'/g, "\\'") + "</style>');}(window.jQuery));";
        this.queue(compiled);
        return this.queue(null);
    });
};
```